# One Post From Each User query via Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a query resolver via Sequelize and node.js

There are 3 models as `Group`, `Post` and `User`.
I want to fetch Posts (one post from each user) that sent to Group.
The associations are like that.

```
Group.belongsToMany(Post, { through:'GroupPost' });

Post.belongsToMany(Group, { through:'GroupPost' });

Post.belongsTo(User, { as:'creator' });

User.hasMany(Post, { as:'createdPosts' });
```

And my actual resolver for `Group.inbox` is:

```
Post.findAll({
    where: { targetId: group.id },
    order: [['id', 'DESC']],
    limit: first || last,  // I use Relay-Cursor-Connections
    include: [{
        model: User,
        association: 'creator',
        duplicating: false,
    }]
});
```

But this resolver does not give me the expected result. It returns all the Posts that sent to Group.

I want to fetch Posts (one post from each user) that sent to Group.
How can I do that ???

Comment: Check group by. I suggest you write the query in SQL first and then try to implement in sequelize query.